# Should I use C for post Exploitation

Tags: network, penetration-test, attacks

Once I have gained shell access to a box on a remote network, is it most efficient if I use the C programming language to create some tools to use for learning about the network and further exploiting it, or is it possible to get nmap and other ready made tools inside of the network?

Comment: if you have sufficient privileges on the remote system you can simply install whatever tools you need on that system. If you want to create your own from scratch, writing them in Python will likely be faster than writing them in C

Comment: Efficiency is defined by accomplishing a goal with the fewest resources. You have not explained your goal or your resources, so I'm not sure this question is answerable. The way you've asked it, building your own tools is not as efficient as using pre-built ones...

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this very much depends on the circumstances.

- If you're on a time-limited test or exam situation, then I'd recommend against trying to write your own C-based tools as part of post-exploitation.  It would be very time consuming and likely not the best way to approach it, as there are a huge number of post-exploitation tools that have had 1000's of hours of development time and you don't want to replicate that.
- If you're doing this purely for your own research/education and have no time constraints then, sure, something like C or Go would be a good language to write things in as they're cross platform and have minimal dependencies once compiled.

Comment: I found this answer very informative. Let's say if we really need to stick to the platform, could python be the 3rd choice?

Comment: Go is a really interesting platform for developing post-exploitation tools. Its fast and compiled like C, but has really awesome system and networking libraries, and cross compilation is cake.